# What does ccw do in Vim macro

Tags: vim, vim-macros

In the following vim macro [from this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/05/11/vim-grep-find-all-occurrences-of-text-in-your-project/), the author gives an explanation. I understand some but not everything.

```
:qccwcommand<Esc>:w<Ctl-W>jj<Enter>q
```

This macro (which includes the record start / stop, if you’re wondering) will change the current ‘path_to_command’ word to ‘command’, write the file out to disk, change window splits to the grep search results, move down one line in the results and navigate to that result’s location.

Q1. What is `ccw` doing here? Is it something to do with `cw` (change word) but I am not sure.

Q2. :w must be to write, right?.

Q3. What is `<Ctrl-W>jj` doing here? The following is what `:h CTRL-W_J` is about but I am not sure if I am looking into the correct help nor the meaning of the help in this context.

```
                                        *CTRL-W_J*
CTRL-W J    Move the current window to be at the very bottom, using the
    full width of the screen.  This works like closing the current
    window and then creating another one with ":botright split",
    except that the current window contents is used for the new
    window.
```

Comment: Try typing the macro in yourself, you'll see what it does.

Comment: (I mean without the `qc` leader and `q` trailer)

Answer (score 5):

you're confused because `ccw` taken literally in that sequence of commands dosen't really make sense!

the initial `qc` means "start macro recording in register c"

then the next `cw` means change word  (e.g. delete the next word and leave editor in insert mode)

also notice that the final command is a `q`:  this means to finish the macro recording.  Macros are super useful when doing things that require a lot of repetition!!1  --> http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros

---

then, his explanation in the blog post contains the answer to Q2 and Q3

```
This macro (which includes the record start / stop, if you’re wondering)
will change the current ‘path_to_command’ word to ‘command’, write the file
out to disk, change window splits to the grep search results, move down one
line in the results and navigate to that result’s location. I ran the macro
by hitting @c and then verifying the line selected was one that I wanted to
change. For a few instances where I did not want to change the line, I
manually navigated to the next search result and then re-ran the @c macro.
```

Q2 - yup, to save the file:  "`write the file out to disk`"

Q3 - the `<Ctl-W>jj<Enter>` is a sequence of Vim key commands to **move to the next entry in the quickfix window** from the vimgrep, as he indicates:  "`write the file
    out to disk, change window splits to the grep search results, move down one
    line in the results and navigate to that result’s location.`"